# Updating Score column based upon the other column of the same Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am using this data set [image] and i need to update the value of the 'Score' columns if the 'like' of the User is less than the data['like'].mean()
i am trying to iterate through Rows and updating it using this code:-

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if row['like'] < data.like.mean():
        row['Score'] +=10
```

but nothing is happening, Scores are not getting updated according to users like value, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: There's no column named `life`. Do you mean `data[like].mean()`?

Comment: i have update it, thanks

Comment: @desertnaut sorry, i didn't tried to spam, it was a mistake, apologies.

Comment: No worries, just keep it mind for the next time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.loc[df['like'].lt(df['like'].mean()), 'Score'] += 10
```